# Compare SQL Count

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to return the `name`, which has not the `con_id` nr `2` and has more objects `(count(*))` than in `con_id` nr `2`.

My statement isnt working because of the `count`.. can someone help me pls

```
Select v.name
From CDB_objects c, v\$containers v, CDB_objects c2
Where object_type like '%JAVA%'
   And c.con_id = v.con_id
   And owner not in ('MDSYS', 'OJVMSYS')
   And c.con_id != 2
   And c.count(*) < c2.count(*)
   Group by v.name;
```

the return statement without the compare looks like this

```
OWNER                STATUS      CNT NAME
-------------------- -------- ------ ---------------
SYS                  VALID     37337 CDB$ROOT
SYS                  VALID     37451 PDB1
SYS                  VALID     37339 PDB2
SYS                  VALID     37338 PDB3
```

Comment: Calculate counts with subqueries and then compare them

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  You also need to learn proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WHERE` clause is applied before `GROUP BY`. What you're looking for is `HAVING`

Also you don't have any join condition with c2, and those expressions: `c.count(*)`, `c2.count(*)` are not syntactically correct.

Anyway I think you need a simple query like this

```
select v.name
  from cdb_objects c, v$containers v
 where object_type like '%JAVA%'
   and c.con_id = v.con_id
   and owner not in ('MDSYS', 'OJVMSYS')
   and c.con_id != 2
 group by v.name
having count(*) < (select count(*) from cdb_objects c2 where c2.con_id = 2)
```

Comment: Thanks mate it really helped i forgot  the having function..  :´ )